# Exposing endpoint URL in tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

Let's go straight to the problem:

I want to test a method that wants URL of Rest endpoint as a parameter. That method is using `RestTemplate` internally to send a request to that URL, so it needs to be full URL, for example http://localhost:8080/rest. Because of that I also have no way to mock `RestTemplate`.

I wanted to create simple `@RestController` but it seems that Spring is not creating endpoint when running tests.

I've tried creating MockMvc but it's not what I want. I have no way of getting the IP and port of MockMvc's created endpoint because no actual endpoint is created.

So, what I want is to make my `@RestController` accessible in tests by sending requests to URL, for example: http://localhost:8080/rest.

It's my first time creating a test like that, I will be grateful for your help. I was searching for an answer but I couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Edit:
Here's some code:

Unfortunately I can't post all the code but what I'm posting should be enough:

I have my endpoint like(names changed):

```
@RestController
public class EndpointController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Output> doSomething(@RequestBody Input[] requestList){
        ...
    }

}
```

It's endpoint only for testing, it mimics the real endpoint. Then during my test I'm creating an object like:

```
new EndpointClient("http://localhost:8080/rest")
```

which has inside something like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Output[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(endpointURL,HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Output[].class);
```

Method having `restTemplate` request isn't called directly during testing(it's called by another method).

So I need to pass that URL to the Client object.

Comment: I don't see why the `RestTemplate` cannot be mocked.  Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem.

I did it with WireMock: http://wiremock.org/

First I had to create Transformer for my request, so the response depends on request, something like:

```
public class MyTransformer extends ResponseTransformer {

    @Override
    public Response transform(final Request request,
                              final Response response,
                              final FileSource fileSource,
                              final Parameters parameters){
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(new HttpHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"));
        if(request.getUrl().contains("/rest")){
            ...
            return Response.Builder.like(response).but().body(...).headers(headers).build();
        } else
            return Response.Builder.like(response).but().status(404).headers(headers).build();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "swapper";
    }
}
```

In my test I needed to put

```
WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(3665).extensions("package.name.endpoint.MyTransformer"));
server.stubFor(post("/rest"));
```

It created exactly what I wanted. Code above is extremely simple, probably not that good and needs work but it shows the basics.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your web application, checkout the [Getting Started: Testing the Web Layer](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) documentation.

Spring Boot is providing some useful annotations like `@SpringBootTest`, `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`, ...
See also the `TestRestTemplate`, which can be autowired to your WebMvcTest.

**edit**:
An example, copied from the documentation mentioned above:

```
package hello;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class HttpRequestTest {

@LocalServerPort
private int port;

@Autowired
private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
public void greetingShouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
    assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/",
            String.class)).contains("Hello World");
    }
}
```